# Is it possible to disable ProxyCount from Scoping tags when using Spring SAML Implementation

Tags: azure, spring-saml

Azure does not support several options for SCOPING and it appears that ProxyCount is one of them. ProxyCount is sent as part of the SCOPING tag by default with Spring SAML no matter if it is set to 0 or not.

Is there a way to disable the ProxyCount option from being sent with SCOPING or is there another workaround found to use SCOPING with Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and am working with a legacy application that doesn't have Spring Boot and uses XML for the configuration but I got it to remove the scoping tag by editing the following bean and setting the `includeScoping` property to `false`.

If you are using Spring Boot or Java configurations there is probably something similar to this.

```
<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Once the scoping tag was removed the SAML SSO integration with Azure worked.